# CSS & JS & images = 404 for WordPress blog in Rails + Nginx environment

Tags: nginx, wordpress, ruby-on-rails, fastcgi

I'm pulling out my hair on this one.

You can see yourself here - **http://starterpad.com/blog/** - that all the images, CSS, and JS files are 404 errors.

The main StarterPad site (http://starterpad.com) is running Rails, and it seems fine.  But the /blog is WordPress and it has seen better days.

Here's our nginx.conf file:

```
user  apache;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}



http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.24;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby;


    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile       on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

#    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


server {
  server_name www.starterpad.com;
  return 301 $scheme://starterpad.com$request_uri;
}


  upstream starterpad {
    server unix:///var/www/starterpad.com/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name starterpad.com vps.starterpad.com;
    root /var/www/starterpad.com/current/public; 
    error_log /var/www/starterpad.com/shared/log/nginx_error.log;
    access_log off;

    error_page 403 404          /404.html;
    error_page 422              /422.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /500.html;

    location ^~ /assets|uploads/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location @starterpad {
        proxy_pass http://starterpad; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location / {
        try_files /index.html $uri.html $uri @starterpad;
    }

    location /blog/ {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
        #deny all;      
        root /var/www/starterpad.com/blog;       
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        include wpsecure.conf;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;        
    }
    location ~ \.php {
        root /var/www/starterpad.com/blog;
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }    
  }
}
```

Here's some errors from the error log, but they don't seem helpful to me:

> 2015/01/26 22:16:06 [error] 11511#0: *11 open()
>   "/var/www/starterpad.com/blog/blog/wp-content/themes/sparkling/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 173.245.48.128, server:
>   starterpad.com, request: "GET
>   /blog/wp-content/themes/sparkling/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=4.1
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "starterpad.com", referrer:
>   "http://starterpad.com/blog/"
>
> 2015/01/26 19:22:26 [error] 10431#0: *28798 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "Unable to open primary script:
>   /var/www/starterpad.com/blog/b6d767d2f8ed5d21a44b0e5886680cb9/generator.php
>   (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: 108.162.215.123, server: starterpad.com, request:
>   "POST /b6d767d2f8ed5d21a44b0e5886680cb9/generator.php HTTP/1.1",
>   upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "starterpad.com",
>   referrer:
>   "http://starterpad.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/SoftwareProgrammer-750x410.jpg"

I've read so many Stack Overflow and other pages, tried almost everything in the nginx.conf, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?  You'd be my frickin' hero!

Comment: Look at your error log.

Comment: nginx error log has nothing useful.  Is there another error log I should be looking at?

Comment: I posted a couple possibly-useful error messages above

Comment: Yes, the first error makes it blatantly obvious what's going on.

Comment: Oh duh!  Double /blog lol

Comment: Now I can view images and such, but the actual blog is down lol...can't figure out what nginx config changes so EVERYTHING works...reverting back

Comment: GOT IT, thanks @MichaelHampton - if you want to answer the question I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out (thanks to [MichaelHampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton)).  The changed rows are in bold below.

---

location /blog/ {
**root /var/www/starterpad.com;**
include wpsecure.conf;
index index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ .php$ {
root /var/www/starterpad.com/blog;
**try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;**
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}